# PHP + PostGresql + stored procedure

Tags: php, postgresql, stored-procedures, return, call

I have the next procedure in postgresql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION suma (INTEGER,INTEGER) RETURNS INTEGER AS $$
DECLARE
    RES INTEGER;
BEGIN   
    RES := $1 + $2;
    RETURN RES;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

I want to call in php and show value of the procedure in this case RES, i have this in php but i dont know hot to get that value

```
$db = new PDO("pgsql:dbname=test003;host=localhost", "postgres", "root" );

    $sql = 'CALL suma(?, ?)';
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);

    $x = 1;
    $y = 2;

    $stmt->bindValue(1, $x, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindValue(2, $y, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();

    echo "PDO connection object created ". $x . " " . $y;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use "select" instead of "call" command